# hugo mod get issue getting missing dot error

Tags: module, hugo

I am using a BRANCHed version of a Forked version of BeutifulHugo theme.
It was working fine yesterday, but now...

```
% hugo mod get -u ./...                    

Update module in /Users/<username>/HUGO/CSTest/TLP-CSMAIN005/TLP-CSMAIN005
go: malformed module path "HTheme-beautifulhugo": missing dot in first path element
```

*** .gitmodules ***

```
[submodule "themes/HTheme-beautifulhugo"]
    path = themes/HTheme-beautifulhugo
    url = https://github.com/TLPub/HTheme-beautifulhugo
    branch = Dev001
```

All I want to do is pull the changes I made to the Dev001 branch into the site.
Need assistance on why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue in a rather non-elegant way.
I removed all references to the theme from the Main repo, including some manual work, then did a...

```
git submodule add -b Dev001 -f https://github.com/TLPhing/HTheme-beautifulhugo themes/HTheme-beautifulhugo
```

The ...
-b is the branch I modify

- f is to force, although probably not necessary.

This worked and I'll add to a make file.

Run git rm , and commit.
This removes the filetree at , and the submodule's entry in the .gitmodules file. I.e. all traces of the submodule in your repository proper are removed.

As the docs note however, the .git dir of the submodule is kept around (in the modules/ directory of the main project's .git dir), "to make it possible to checkout past commits without requiring fetching from another repository".
If you nonetheless want to remove this info, manually delete the submodule's directory in .git/modules/, and remove the submodule's entry in the file .git/config. These steps can be automated using the commands

rm -rf .git/modules/, and
git config --remove-section submodule..